# What is the technical name of an obround cylinder?

Tags: shapes, terminology

I know that a 2-dimensional rectangle that has semicircular ends instead of flat ones is called [an 'obround' or a 'stadium'](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Stadium.html), but what is the name of a three-dimensional rectangular cuboid that has semicircular, and not flat, edges, like the one in this photo? Is 'obround cylinder' an appropriate name?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!

Comment: The 2D shape is also known as a racetrack, in many cad applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen a patent description which says "obround extrusion" It's this https://patents.google.com/patent/EP2149663A1/en. At least it was understood in 2008. The shape is part number 20.

The same shape in the patent was also described as oblong with rounded ends in the cross-section. "Oblong" in that place means that it's  taller than wide.